# dynamic and multiple subscription/publishing channels with django-websocket-redis?

Tags: django, websocket, socket.io

I want users to be able to chat in multiple 'channels' at a time on the same page - basically, there are a few chat windows one a page, based on user preference and all the messages are persisted and when a user opens a specific chat window I want him to see all messages that were ever posted to this chat. There is little documentation available on the framework, I can't figure out the best way to implement this:

- List of channels is hardcoded in RedisSubscriber class - how do I allow dynamic channels to be added to the list?
- What's the best way to work with multiple channels? Use a single channel and 'filter' messages to show for the entity based on some unique ID (could not find this functionality in ws4redis.js) or just do multiple subscriptions?
- is django-websocket-redis a good match for this in general?